# Terraform - Failed to set up SSH tunneling for host

Tags: ssh, terraform, rke

Hell, I am trying to deploy rke k8s with terraform, but I am not able to connect to the desired host via ssh:

```
 time="2022-02-28T11:17:38+01:00" level=warning msg="Failed to set up SSH tunneling for host [poc-k8s.my-domain.com]: Can't retrieve Docker Info: error during connect: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/info\": Unable to access node with address [poc-k8s.my-domain.com:22] using SSH. Please check if you are able to SSH to the node using the specified SSH Private Key and if you have configured the correct SSH username. Error: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain"
```

and this is the `.tf` file I am using:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    rke = {
      source = "rancher/rke"
      version = "1.3.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "rke" {
  log_file = "rke_debug.log"
}


resource "rke_cluster" "cluster" {
  nodes {
    address = "poc-k8s.my-domain.com"
    user    = "root"
    role    = ["controlplane", "worker", "etcd"]
    ssh_key = file("~/.ssh/root_key")
  }
  nodes {
    address = "poc-k8s.my-domain.com"
    user    = "root"
    role    = ["worker", "etcd"]
    ssh_key = file("~/.ssh/root_key")
  }
  addons_include = [
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml",
    "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/superseb/499f2caa2637c404af41cfb7e5f4a938/raw/930841ac00653fdff8beca61dab9a20bb8983782/k8s-dashboard-user.yml",
  ]
}

resource "local_file" "kube_cluster_yaml" {
  filename = "~/.kube/kube_config_cluster.yml"
  sensitive_content  = "rke_cluster.cluster.kube_config_yaml"
}
```

The key if of course correct and I am able to connect to the desired host:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/root_key root@poc-k8s.my-domain.com
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: This seems more like a Docker error. Which OS are you running terraform apply on?

Comment: @MarkoE Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Could be a combination of sudo and Docker is tripping you up.

Answer (score 0):

[Update]

Cluster resource has `delay_on_creation` property that can be used

```
resource "rke_cluster" "cluster" {

  delay_on_creation = 180     

  (...)
}
```

---

I'm facing a similar issue. On the second run of terrafor apply it works correctly. In my case the issue is that docker is not up fast enough for RKE provider.

I've found following workaround from [citynetwork /
citycloud-examples](https://%20https://github.com/citynetwork/citycloud-examples/blob/69a534a2bdc363992012f46a00268940328cd59a/rancher-example/rke_k8s_cluster.tf#L35):

```
resource "rke_cluster" "cluster" {     

  (...)

  depends_on = [null_resource.wait-for-docker]
}

resource "null_resource" "wait-for-docker" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sleep 180"
  }
  depends_on = [

  # list of servers docker being installed on

  (...) 

  ]
}
```

It waits for 180s which is not ideal, though.